# Python: Find Surrounding parts of a string with irrelevant section in the middle

Tags: python, string, find, partial, surround

So I have a large string with several similar things. I want to find part of a string but have part of it be irrelevant.

For example:
"0"
blah"11"
"0"
blah"3"
"0"
blah"6"
"0"
blah"600"
"0"

I want to find ' blah"..." '
Where '...' is the number and I can get the value of '...'

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'blah"(\d+)"','"0" blah"11" "0" blah"3" "0" blah"6" "0" blah"600" "0"')
['11', '3', '6', '600']
```